# Visual C++ incorrect argument type, expects type being used

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am coding a windows app in visual C++ for the surface, and trying to read in data from a file stored in the pictures library.

```
            auto file = Windows::Storage::StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync("C:\\data.txt");
            concurrency::create_task(Windows::Storage::FileIO::ReadTextAsync(file)).then([this, file](concurrency::task<Platform::String^> task)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Platform::String^ fileContent = task.get();
                    }
                });
```

However, when trying to create a task to read the data, it errors with:

"Error: no instance of overloaded function "Windows::Storage::FileIO::ReadTextAsync" matches the argument list.  Argument types are: (Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation <>Windows::Storage::StorageFile ^> ^)"

However, Visual Studio tells me the variable type is indeed "Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<>Windows::Storage::StorageFile ^> ^file."
I'm unsure why this is not compatible.

Comment: This isn't [tag:c++]. It's either [tag:c++-cli] or [tag:c++-cx]. We don't know, which one it is. @drecherjm probably picked the wrong one in their edit.

Comment: You are reading the error message wrong. It is telling you what you passed, not what it expects. It expects a `StorageFile^` but you are passing an `IAsyncOperation<StorageFile^>^`. You forgot to `.then` the `GetFileFromPathAsync`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Raymond.  Could you offer any insight on how to asynchronously acquire the file path to use for ReadTextAsync()?  I have tried and failed many times to call it on a Storage File, but can not seem to make it the correct argument type.  I can call GetFileFromPathAsync in a task, but I'm not sure how to reference it from there to get the actual text from the file.